# What is the format for nesting one microdata itemscope inside of another?

Tags: seo, microdata

I'm new to SEO and heard that using microdata tags in html can dramatically improve SEO. So, for one of my pages, the schema type is an organization... in particular a sports team. One of the properties for a sports team is the members. So, I have the following code:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SportsTeam">
   <span itemprop="name">New York Yankees</span>
   <span itemprop="members">Derek Jeter</span>
</div>
```

The "members" itemprop has to be a person itemscope (http://schema.org/Person). What is the format for nesting one itemscope inside of another?

Comment: After looking it up, microdata seems a lot like a structured partial integration of XML into HTML. Interesting.

Comment: @JAB: “microdata seems a lot like a structured partial integration of XML into HTML” — nope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Google article on microdata tags](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176035):

---

The example below shows the same HTML, but in this case, it includes the address property.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Person">
   My name is <span itemprop="name">Bob Smith</span>, 
   but people call me <span itemprop="nickname">Smithy</span>.
   Here is my homepage: 
   <a href="http://www.example.com" itemprop="url">www.example.com</a>.
   I live in 
   <span itemprop="address" itemscope
      itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Address">
      <span itemprop="locality">Albuquerque</span>, 
      <span itemprop="region">NM</span> 
   </span>
   and work as an <span itemprop="title">engineer</span>
   at <span itemprop="affiliation">ACME Corp</span>.
</div>
```

Here's how this sample works:

The `address` property is itself an item, containing its own set of properties. This is indicated by putting the `itemscope` attribute on the item that declares the `address` property, and using the `itemtype` attribute to specify the type of item being described, like this: `<span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Address">`.

---

I would add that microtags are in their infancy, so you cannot guarantee that the specification will remain intact for very long. I personally predict that the blackhat SEO guys are going to be all over this, and it'll be a headache for Google to keep up with the tricks. So, whilst they might provide you a temporary SEO boost, don't rely on them too heavily.

On a more positive note, I can certainly see these microtags being useful for non-SEO purposes, especially in the field of screen-readers. Fun stuff!

Comment: I was adding an answer, but this beats anything I would have written. I do want to call out that http://diveintohtml5.info/extensibility.html  has a good reference as well

Comment: Interesting. So, what is a more secure alternative for a SEO boost? If microdata tags are still in their infancy, what's more reiable?

Comment: @Lance SEO is a massive subject. For on-page SEO, go for microdata tags, properly filled meta tags (esp. tags, description, language) and title, SEO-friendly URLs (e.g. `/1234/name-of-page`), plenty of quality keyword-rich content. Avoid stuffing, that'll get you dumped in the sandbox.

Comment: @Lance I also highly recommend setting up a blog, and other social media presences, with plenty of backlinks into your pages. Try to anchor your links with content appropriate for the target page, too. Going on and on about a particular product and then linking to the homepage of your company's site isn't very good for SEO, whereas linking to that product's page is much more useful.

Comment: Okay, what exactly is an SEO friendly URL? I've been messing around with modrewrite lately to make the URLs cleaner. For example, www.mysite.com/teams.php?team=New York Yankees&year=2012 would become www.mysite.com/teams/New York Yankees/2012. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Kinda, yeah. Take a look at how StackOverflow does it. Generally you'd use URL rewriting to convert `/123/page-name-here` to something like `page.php?id=123`. The text on the end is (generally) ignored by the rewrite rule. Give it a go, change the text on the end of your question's URL and see what happens. The result is that your anchor text has keywords that match the URL, and the same keywords show up on the page too. That results in the highest weight being added to a backlink.

Comment: I also recommend checking out the [SEO] tag on Webmasters SE: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo - it's a great place to ask questions about SEO and get informed answers.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'll look into it. Interesting what you said about meta tags. From a lot of what i've read, they're very outdated and aren't as important as microdata and sitemaps.

Comment: Tags / description meta tags are rather outdated, but it never hurts to include them. Some people still use old search engines, many of which rely solely on meta tags. It's still important to include meta tags for language, encoding, charset, etc.

Comment: Here's a great quote about the perfect page in terms of SEO: "Is relevant to the terms being searched for, is considered an authority about its topic, has good, useful content, has been around for a while, is part of a site with lots of information, loads quickly, doesn't have a bunch of broken links, and isn't filled with a cheap list of keywords." - sadly, achieving that isn't as easy as writing it!